# Data.model.updateItem is not a function TypeError: Data.model.updateItem is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

Error in keystone js using mongo : Vehicle.model.updateItem is not a function TypeError: Vehicle.model.updateItem is not a function .

The goal is to update the model using an object just like how I did create Items using the ff. code below.

## CreateItems - Vehicle is the model. and postJson is the json array object.

```
keystone.createItems({
        Vehicle: postJson
      }, function (err, stats) {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        res.json({
          data: stats.message
        });

        console.log("Succeeded!!")
      });
```

Now I am trying to update data on the model using an json array of object and with the unique id where itemToUpdate is the query to match the document I want to update and the fieldToUpdate is the object containing the field/fields you want a new value for. But it raises an error Vehicle.model.updateItem is not a function TypeError: Vehicle.model.updateItem is not a function

## Update Code

```
  var itemToUpdate = {
              vin_no: value.vin_no
            }

            var fieldToUpdate = {
              Vehicle: value
            }

        Vehicle.model.updateItem(
          itemToUpdate,
          fieldToUpdate,
          function (err, stats) {
            if (err) return res.json(err);
            res.json({
              data: stats.message
            });

            console.log("Succeeded!!")
          })
```

Any idea how we can update data using objects. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use it like this

```js
// assuming value is object with all the fields. 
var itemToUpdate = {
    vin_no: value.vin_no
}

Vehile.model.findOne(itemToUpdate, function(error, vehicleObject) {

    Vehicle.updateItem(
        vehicleObject,
        value,
        function (err) {
            // err can be Error object or an object with 'error' and/or 'detail' property
            if (err) return res.json(err);

            res.json({
                status: "success"
            });

            console.log("Succeeded!!")
        })
})
```

if `itemToUpdate` has variable number of fields, you can add option to this call as

```
var options = { field: 'vin_no, model_year, num_owners' }
```

and pass this as `Vehicle.updateItem(Vehicle.model, itemToUpdate, options, callback)`

Comment: assuming `vin_no, model_year, num_owners` are the fields you want to update form the itemToUpdate object which may have other fields.

Comment: How about those values i wanted to use on updating the data ?

Comment: you have to loop through and repeat, you can also make use of `async.forEach` for this.